# Why does my apps disappear randomly after a reboot?

Tags: applications, reboot, lg-g3

Sometimes when I reboot my LG G3 (about every other time I do that) some apps show up in the main screen with the default Android icon and the app name underneath, but when I tap to open the app it says "Application not instaled". When I look for the app in the app list it does not show up there.

This problem usually happens to Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Translate, Google Photos or Google Maps. Less comonly also happens to other apps too, but the mentioned ones are responsible by the vast majority of the "app abduction" phenomena. It does not happen necessarily with all of them at same time, sometimes one or two, sometimes 6 or 7, being the mentioned ones the usual victims.

I saw some people who reported this problem in other LG devices when the apps are moved to the SD card, but I don't use any SD card on my phone.

I'm afraid that my SSD is dying. The problem with other people pointed to Android having difficulty to read the app from the external SD card. Since in my case the apps are installed in the SSD, so it may be failing intermittently. The phone sometimes freezes and reboots itself from time to time too.

Comment: The LG G3 was released May 28, 2014, putting it at about 3.5 years old, that coupled with the other issues you are having lend to your deduction that the eMMC (internal storage) chip is failing. If it was me, I would look at replacing this device as soon as possible.

Comment: That's sad that a single component failure is junking the whole device. I want to replace only with a device that is more serviceable. I do not want to make handset makers happy because my phone failed.

Comment: Well, then you are in for a real disappointment... All devices are this way and have been for well over 5 years, they are not desktop computers where you can just swap out a video card, hard drive, processor, or power supply. Although, some mobile devices have some replaceable parts such as the headset jack, USB port, screen, or camera module, in general core components like internal storage, processor, RAM, etc. are all micro-soldered to the main board, the only way to service it would be to replace the entire board. Modern devices are engineered to last about 2 years, sometimes you get more.

Comment: It is possible. It is just that the manufacturers solder everything in to prevent servicing. There were a few Fairphone built but I guess that they may have difficulties to get investment since they don't practise programmed obsolence.

Comment: I never said it was impossible, only that you would (likely) be disappointed looking for a more serviceable device. It is possible for people with the correct skills and equipment... but it is not possible for the average enthusiast, much less a "normal" user. Like or not, things in life are becoming more and more disposable.

Comment: So I will dispose my interest on smartphones :-)